# Javascript random code for selecting array not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

```js
function whosPaying(name) {
  var position = name.length;

  var randomPerson = Math.floor(Math.random() * position);

  console.log(name[randomPerson] + " is going to buy lunch.");
}


whosPaying("Jack", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe");
```

When I run this code to get output in console log instead of selecting a name it selects  one letter from the the first name (here:jack).

Comment: Because `name` only contains the string `"Jack"`. Why do you think `name` would be an array?

Comment: You should pass array instead whosPaying(["Jack", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe"]);

Comment: The problem is that you're not using an array. To pass an array into `whosPaying`, create an array (with `[]`): `whosPaying(["Jack", "Ben", ...]);` (Or use a rest parameter.)

Answer (score 1):

Use rest parameters instead, so you can get all arguments as an array, then choose a random item from the array:

```js
function whosPaying(...people) {
  const randomPerson = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
  console.log(randomPerson + " is going to buy lunch.");
}


whosPaying("Jack", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe");
```

Or pass an array instead of multiple arguments:

```js
function whosPaying(people) {
  const randomPerson = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];
  console.log(randomPerson + " is going to buy lunch.");
}


whosPaying(["Jack", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are passing strings. Pass it as an array 
You should pass array instead `whosPaying(["Jack", "Ben", "Jenny", "Michael", "Chloe"]);`